# Select one row from a table by specifying the row number (Databse)

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ms-access

I am currently working on a C# .Net program. This program is connected to an MS Access database.
I am trying to select just one row from a table by specifying the row number, but I can not find any solution for that.
I hope you can help me with my problem :)

Comment: Tables don't have row numbers, unless you have a column with that information.  Normally you would use the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

You should use primary key or unique column to get 1 row correct data. Other way is very manually and painfull in my opinion. Example

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE CustomerID=1;
```

CostumerID is primary key and it bring 1 row to result. If do you realy want to make it manualy i advise add a datagridview in your project and make its visible to false. Fill your all data into it and get what do you want in it. You can access each row easyly.